# Cannot call a function in AJAX success

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am unable to use most jQuery in Ajax success. I am trying to have an error message from the response appear in my notify (toast) div, but anything I try except `.show()` and `.hide()` will not work.

I have used `console.log()` to ensure it is definitely decoding the response from the url and everything is as it should, however I am unable to call functions inside the Ajax success function

This is my current JS which triggers at the click of a button.

```
function errMsg(code, msg) {
    const eCode = '<b>E-NS: ' + code + ' </b> </br>' + msg;
    const eMsg = '<span class="err" style="color: red;">' + eCode + '</span>';
    
    $('.notify').empty().html(eMsg);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next-1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:'../data.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-1').serializeArray(),
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(response){
                    if(response.status === true){
                        $('#form-1').hide();
                        $('#form-2').show();
                    } else {
                        console.log(response.status);
                        console.log('Response = ' + response.code + response.error);
                        errMsg(response.code, response.error);
                        var eCode = '<b>E-NS: ' + response.code + ' </b> </br>' + response.error;
                        var eMsg = '<span class="err>' + eCode + '</span>';

                        $('.notify').empty().html(eMsg);
                        
                    }
                }
            })
    })
)}
```

It should be noted that there are no errors or warnings in the php or the jQuery appearing. I am new to AJAX, so I'm not entirely sure if this is something I am able to do, although it seems logical enough, no?

Comment: Accepting an answer marks your question as _solved_. There is no need to add that to the title or post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hiding my toast div (`$('.notify')`) until there was text inside the div. However, I neglected to add my function that showed this -- Which can be seen below -- and did not call it after updating the toast in the AJAX `success` function with `errorCheck()`

```
function errorCheck() {
    if ($('.notify').text().trim().length == 0) {
        $('.notify').hide();
    } else {
        var time =  setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.notify').fadeOut('200');
                    }, 5000);
        $('.notify')
            .show()
            .mouseout(function () {
                time;
            })
            .mouseover(function () {
                clearTimeout(time);
            })
            .click(function() {
                $('.notify').fadeOut('100');
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When sending data as `JSON` the jQuery method `.ajax()` expects an object in the `data` property of the object that is passed as the only argument. Your `jQuery.serialize()` function creates an argument string for a URL. This will not work here. You should instead use `jQuery.serializeArray()`:

```js
function errMsg(code, msg) {
    const eCode = '<b>E-NS: ' + code + ' </b> </br>' + msg;
    const eMsg = '<span class="err" style="color: red;">' + eCode + '</span>';
    
    $('.notify').html(eMsg);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form-2").hide();
    $('#next-1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log("this will be sent to the server:",$('#form-1').serializeArray());
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', // '../data.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:  $('#form-1').serializeArray(),
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(response){
                    // console.log("this came back from the server:",response);
                    if(response){
                        $('#form-1').hide();
                        $('#form-2').show();
                        errMsg(response.id, JSON.stringify(response))
                    } else {
                        console.log(response.status);
                        console.log('Response = ' + response.code + response.error);
                        errMsg(response.code, response.error);
                    }
                }
            })
    })
})
```

```css
.notify {border: 1px solid grey}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-1">
First form ... <br>
<input type="text" name="title" value="my very own title"><br>
<input type="text" name="size" value="XL"><br>
<input type="number" name="quantity" value="3"><br>
<button id="next-1" type="button">OK</button>
</form>

<form id="form-2">
Second form ... <br>
<input type="text" name="title" value="some other product title"><br>
<input type="text" name="size" value="M"><br>
<input type="number" name="quantity" value="5"><br>
<button id="next-2" type="button">OK</button>
</form>

<div class="notify">This is the place for messages ...</div>
```

You should also check what the server will send back. In the case of my dummy JSON API there was not `.status` property being sent back. So it did not make sense to test for it.

Comment: I have updated .serialize() to .serializeArray() and can see that it takes it from being a full string to an array of data, so thank you for that. However, all of the responses return correctly and even display in the console.log. Even the status which returns true when all input fields are validated. The jQuery version I have is 3.7.0 min.


 You can see my console with php and JS logs [here](https://ibb.co/fpVByVL)

Comment: Are you saying your `$('.notify').empty().html(eMsg)` expression does not work?

Comment: That's right. It just doesn't do anything at all. I can't call functions like my `errMsg()` function either.

Comment: But if your response finished without error, it means `else` block just has been ignored, isn't it?

Comment: @lezhni, But if that were the case, then nothing would log to the console, would it not? Plus, an expression like `$('notify').show()` works just fine. It just doesn't seem to want to append or edit html

Comment: Are you sure the `".notify"` element exists and can be found in your HTML (you haven't pusblished it)? I changed my code now, so `errMsg()` will be called in both cases and it works. Btw.: you don't need to call `.empty()` before `.html()` - the innerHTML of the selected element(s) will be replaced in any case.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann If you [see here](https://ibb.co/4jLDTvD) It definitely exists within the DOM. Its default setting is display: none; when there is no text present. But I tried it in a newly created div with the class .toast , which is always visible. Still no luck.  -- Also, regarding the empty() call, I have removed it. Thank you.